# Unable to connect to WiFi network after updates

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I'm running 12.04, and had no problems with WiFi until I installed updates last night (there were quite a few, and I'm not sure how to see what was installed). It might be unrelated, but it's the only thing that's changed.

I can no longer connect to my home WiFi network. Some networks (like my Android hotspot) work fine, but connecting to our BT Home Hub just times out and prompts for authentication as well.

The laptop is an HP EliteBook 8470p, which has a 'Centrino Advanced-N 6205' card (reported in lshw, I'm not sure if it's a brand name for another card).

Here's what's in my syslog, the error seems to be 'Failed to insert Dummy STA entry for the AP':

```
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: get_secret_flags: assertion `is_secret_prop (setting, secret_name, error)' failed
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'BTHub3-8ZRT 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'BTHub3-8ZRT'
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: added 'wep_key0' value '<omitted>'
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: added 'wep_tx_keyidx' value '0'
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Sep 17 16:56:43 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p wpa_supplicant[1506]: Trying to authenticate with 00:fe:f4:75:56:50 (SSID='BTHub3-8ZRT' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p wpa_supplicant[1506]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:fe:f4:75:56:50 reason=2
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: [  291.593766] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:fe:f4:75:56:50 by local choice (reason=2)
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p wpa_supplicant[1506]: Trying to associate with 00:fe:f4:75:56:50 (SSID='BTHub3-8ZRT' freq=2412 MHz)
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p wpa_supplicant[1506]: Association request to the driver failed
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: [  291.595197] wlan0: authenticate with 00:fe:f4:75:56:50 (try 1)
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: [  291.597584] wlan0: authenticated
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p kernel: [  291.597763] wlan0: failed to insert Dummy STA entry for the AP (error -17)
Sep 17 16:56:47 richard-HP-EliteBook-8470p NetworkManager[998]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be, and how to fix it?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19593-ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it

**Ubuntu 12.04.  WiFi not working**

Check if the wifi card is blocked (Terminal)

```
rfkill list wlan     (for wifi)
```

OR

```
rfkill list all             (for wifi and bluetooth)
```

**UNBLOCK**:

```
rfkill unblock wlan     (for wifi)
```

OR

```
rfkill unblock all             (for wifi and bluetooth)
```

Restart the network:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: It wasn't blocked, but `sudo service network-manager restart` fixed it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I followed 2 step to enable wireless in my PC

Step 1 : Removed the bcmwl-kernel-source package

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Step 2 : Installed the firmware-b43-installer package.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

And then rebooted my PC .

Finally got my work done. :)